# How to show page generation stats in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Aside from adding a custom timer to measure the beginning and end of a controller's action, is there an easier or more helpful way to show how long a page is really loaded (i.e. show at the bottom of the page: this page is generated in 30.5 seconds)? Note that in Grails, there's the concept of taglibs wherein you can add additional logic after all the processing done in the controller.

I'm actually not yet sure on how controller and taglib works or how the whole page is rendered in Grails, perhaps they are processed in parallel? Feel free to enlighten me on this too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the times spent on the action and to render your gsp (with all its tags), you can use a simple filter to measure that. Take a look at this blogpost: [Profiling web requests in your Grails application](http://techbeats.deluan.com/profiling-web-requests-in-your-grails-application/) (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Regards,
Deluan

Comment: cool stuff! i think this is a good approach. thanks for this!

Comment: The link is broken. The correct link is [that one](http://techbeats.deluan.com/profiling-web-requests-in-your-grails-application/) :-)

Answer (score 2):

there are several ways to get the timing.

- Easiest way is to configure your server to write logs with page generation time
- you could inject your timing into for instance a security filter and the end of your page - but as you already mentioned, even this would mean to reinvent the wheel
- have you checked the plugins?
- - debug plugin gives you timing info on the console http://www.grails.org/plugin/debug
- - perf4j also helps to profile your pages http://www.grails.org/plugin/perf4j

but if you want to present the timing to your users, I would suggest to download the debug plugin, unzip it and check where the timing is measured. You can easily copy this code and use it to output the timing on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Spring Insight](http://www.grails.org/screencast/show/13) with STS. That's absolutely awesome for Grails Application in developpement. Modifying a tomcat for use in poroduction make it a bit tricky though

But you can go down to the duration of each select from hibernate and you have timing metric in real time through the all stack of application

Comment: looks interesting. but i'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA. but if that will help me on profiling Grails app overall, i'm very much willing to switch

Comment: i'm personnaly on NetBeans and never try to develop on STS. But just for short period of debugging, it's a really useful tool. I use it as I would use VisualVM or JConsole

Comment: Spring Insight is awesome! i think i'll be a STS convert now. thank you so much for pointing out this tool.

Comment: I can't do anything but agree :-) Hope this tool proves himself valuable for you in the future

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you asked for (sorry), but maybe of interest is the [JavaMelody plugin for Grails](http://www.grails.org/plugin/grails-melody):

> The goal of [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) is to monitor
>   Java or Java EE application servers in
>   QA and production environments. It is
>   not a tool to simulate requests from
>   users, it is a tool to measure and
>   calculate statistics on real operation
>   of an application depending on the
>   usage of the application by users.

Not tried it myself, but it looks useful

Comment: i tried JavaMelody before and my problem with using that is it causes an OOM error in my site. I'm not saying that the plugin is problematic, probably lack of resource in our server (due to the app server config). but thanks for the reminder to use it :)